# Unity Display Highest 10 Scores

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, save, game-development

I am trying to make like a Scoreboard but for a single player. I want to save my best 10 scores to the board and display it to the MainMenu. So far I know how to save and display only one result. The code is as follows:

```
[SerializeField] private int score;
 
 void Update()
 {
  if (score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highestScore"))
         {
             PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highestScore", score);
         }
 }
```

And I am displaying as follows in my MainMenu scene

```
void Start()
 {
     highScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highestScore").ToString();
 }
```

Is it possible if you help me to save my last 10 best scores and display them? I couldn't find any tutorial on how to do that. I guess I should you array of Ints and loop through that array and then save it to PlayerPrefs but I have no idea how to do that. Hope you will be able to help me and thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely save more keys,
PlayerPrefs
takes parameters one is a key and the second is a value
you can set it up like

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore_1", value);
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore_2", value);
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore_3", value);
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore_4", value);
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore_5", value);
```

So when some one scores more than one of the previous highest score, what you'll do is

```
int newScore = 50;
for(int i=1; i <= 5; i++){
    if(newScore > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highScore_"+i)){
        for(int x = 5; x > i; x--){
            int value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highScore_"+(x-1));
            PlayerPrefs.setInt("highScore_"+x, value);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, It does not seems to be working or I am doing something wrong trying to implement it. It returns the Highest Score to all of the 5 text fields when I am setting up the PlayerPrefs as you mentioned above.

Comment: hey, would you mind trying it again, I've made a correction to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ArrayPrefs2 to store as an array (http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/ArrayPrefs2), then update using:

```
static void UpdateHighScores(int newScore)
{ 
  var highScores = PlayerPrefsX.GetIntArray("highScores");
  if (newScore > highScores[0]) {
    highScores[0] = newScore;
    Array.Sort(highScores);
    PlayerPrefsX.SetIntArray("highScores", highScores);
  }
}
```

After initializing the PlayerPrefs key `"highScores"` somewhere else with:

```
PlayerPrefsX.SetIntArray("highScores", new Array[10]);
```

Note that this produces an array with the lowest high score first and the true highest score last in the array.

Comment: Also I would comment in Hamza Abbas' answer, but I don't have any reputation yet. They forgot to add a `break;` at the end of the if statement.

Comment: Hey, thank you for pointing out that mistake, I didn't try to run to code instead wrote it assuming how it would work, thanks man.

Comment: there was another mistake, the forloop condition was checking X is smaller I, so if I = 3 and X starts at 5 (X < I = 5 < 3) it would always return false, I edited the for-loop condition too.

Comment: No problem. I think you need to change `"highScore_"x-1` to be `"highScore_"+(x-1)` as well. Though if the OP got your code to run they must have already noticed that.

Comment: lmao, edited the answer, is there anything else I'm missing? XD

Comment: Wait, there totally is! `setInt` should be `SetInt` and you're even missing the crucial line of `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highScore_"+i, newScore);` before `break;` I think it might be time to do a brief test.

Comment: yes I can setInt is the problem but anything else if fine, I guess I shouldn't write answers directly on this website instead try them out first, lmao